# Can an abstract class constructor instantiate a new object?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I have a group of services that get injected into my controllers. Can my abstract class constructor instantiate new instances of commonly used objects?

```
public class ReportService : AReportService, IReportService
{
    private readonly IMyService _myservice;
    public ReportService(IMyService myService) : base ()
    {
        _myservice = myService;
    }

    public void MyMethodForThisService(string someProperty)
    {
        _parentService.DoSomething(someProperty);
    }
}

public abstract class AReportService
{
    protected readonly ParentService _parentService;
    protected AReportService()
    {
        _parentService = new ParentService();
    }

    protected void MyFirstSharedMethodForAllServices(string someProperty)
    {
        _parentService.DoSomethingElse(someProperty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon Skeet (as usual) is correct--you *can* do this. However, since you're following a Dependency Injection pattern with your child controllers, you should probably use dependency injection for your parent class as well.

You can do this by injecting the dependency into the parent's constructor, but as you've probably noticed that requires all the child classes to inject the same object and do a pass-through, which can get annoying as you add more dependencies.

Alternatively, you can do Property Injection, but this can make it easy to forget to update unit tests with new properties that need to be injected.

As a compromise, I'll often use Method injection, where the base class has an "InjectDependencies" method that initializes the dependencies. Unfortunately, this disallows you from making your dependencies read-only, and still makes it possible to construct your object without providing dependencies.

A final option would be to create a special class just for containing the parent class's dependencies, and then inject *that* class into the parent class's constructor. Child classes then need only pass through a single parameter into the parent constructor, and you're free to add dependencies in the future, which will not affect the child classes, but will alert unit tests that try to construct the dependency object by hand.

You should also think carefully about whether you're using inheritance in a situation where you should be using composition. Is `MyFirstSharedMethodForAllServices()` just a convenience method that you happen to know that several services will use? Why not just create a separate class with this method, which all of those services can inject? This would give you more flexibility, for example, to unit test `MyFirstSharedMethodForAllServices()` independently. It also leaves your services free to extend some other class based on a more "is a"-style relationship.

Comment: If the services all inherit from my abstract class; would there be any benefit / loss in using inheritance for those instances over injection? The methods on the Abstract class are only ever called inside the services.

Comment: @Robert: I'm a little unclear on what you mean. Are you saying that only ParentService calls `AReportService.MyFirstSharedMethodForAllServices()`?

Comment: @StripplingWarrior Thats a negative ghostrider, I am saying that ReportService and all of its "siblings" call MyFirstSharedMethodForAllServices(string something)

Comment: @Robert: That makes more sense. The answer is yes--you would lose the ability, e.g., to mock the ParentService in unit tests. Any time you call `new XXXService()`, you're losing some of the benefits of dependency injection.

Comment: I see. that makes MyFirstSharedMethodForAllServices very difficult to properly test as well as any method that calls it. I hadn't written real code to do this yet so I hadn't written a test

Comment: @Robert: Exactly. You may want to consider using composition rather than inheritance, as I describe in my most recent update.

Answer (score 5):

> Can my abstract class constructor instantiate new instances of commonly used objects?

Absolutely. The constructor for an abstract class can do basically anything a normal constructor can. The only restriction is that you can only *call* the constructor as part of chaining from another constructor.